# The easiest way to write multiprocessing and multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

To be short，I use python and I have two functions:

```
def func1(item):
    do something

def func2(item):
    do something
    return result
```

And I have a list `list = [item1, item2, ...]`. Each element is the argument of function `func1` and `func2`. That is, I want to do the following two loops:

```
for item in list:
    func1(item)

result_list = [func2(item) for item in list]
```

Now I want to apply `threading` and `multiprocessing` on these two loops. So what is **the easiest way** **(I mean, in just several lines of codes)** to achieve it?

For `multiprocessing` on `func1`, I like the following code:

```
with multiprocessing.Pool(processes = 6) as p:
    p.imap(func1, list)
```

Do we have similar code for other cases? That is, `threading` on `func1` and `func2`, `multiprocessing` on `func2`.

Comment: Not exactly. What about func2? I need to collect the returned result?

Comment: What about it?  You collect the results in exactly the same way: multiprocessing.ThreadPool provides the same api, so you get the results the same you would with multiprocessing.Pool, i.e. either use `map` or iterate an `imap`.  I might have misunderstood, however

Comment: Yeah, it is! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import multiprocessing
import threading

def func1(item):
    do something

def func2(item):
    do something
    return result


# Creating thread
t1 = threading.Thread(target=func1, args=(10,))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=func2, args=(10,))
# starting thread 
t1.start()
t2.start()
# wait until thread is completely executed
t1.join()
t2.join()

# Creating processes
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=func2, args=(10, ))
# Starting processes
p2.start()
# Wait until process is finished
p2.join()
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiprocessing-python-set-1/

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multithreading-python-set-1/

Comment: OP specifically requests threading not multiprocessing on func1 (for some reason)